Excel IF statement in template
I want to make an IF expression in a template that generates data from a external program.
!table!=IF(H_U_B-G=1;"Geponst";"")!

So if the attribute from the external program outputs a "1", I want the result to be the text "Geponst". And if it's not a "1", I want a blank cell as output.
How to achieve this?
I've tried it with 2 columns like below, with a #ERROR# as result.



Column A
Column B




!table!H_U_B-G!
=IF([@Column A]=1;"Geponst";"Niet")



I'm hoping on a Text result.

Welcome to SO. To get a 'blank' cell as output, you use "" (it will show up blank, but ISBLANK won't count it as blank though). From the dataset you've given, it is not quite clear to me where you would expect a 1 to appear though.

Are you mixing up languages maybe? Judging by the expressions and separators you need the Dutch translation of IF: ALS.

The 1 comes from a external program called HiCAD. In this program im making technical drawings and HiCAD gives via a excel template a bills of material list.
And in this list some attributes gives out a 1 or a 0 for true or false.

i'm using the dutch calls.
